# AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encrypt_at_time' in MultiFernet

Tags: python, python-cryptography, fernet

Just Trying to Encrypt the plain text using `MultiFernet`.

My code is:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, MultiFernet

fetnet_keys = [
      Fernet.generate_key(), 
      Fernet.generate_key()
]    
mulfern = MultiFernet(fetnet_keys)
enc = mulfern.encrypt("My Message in Plain Text".encode('utf-8'))

print(enc)
```

When trying to encrypt the plain text I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "encryption1.py", line 21, in <module>
    enc = mulfern.encrypt("My Message in Plain Text".encode('utf-8'))
  File "venv3.8\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 169, in encrypt
    return self.encrypt_at_time(msg, int(time.time()))
  File "venv3.8\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 172, in encrypt_at_time
    return self._fernets[0].encrypt_at_time(msg, current_time)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encrypt_at_time'
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1):

`Fernet.generate_key()` returns a `bytes` object.  That key should be used to initialize a `Fernet` object.  [`MultiFernet()`](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.MultiFernet) takes a list of `Fernet` objects.  Note `MultiFernet` encrypts with the first key in the list, but decrypts by trying each key.

Example:

```py
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet, MultiFernet, InvalidToken

old_key = Fernet(Fernet.generate_key())
new_key = Fernet(Fernet.generate_key())

mulfern = MultiFernet([new_key, old_key])

old_enc = old_key.encrypt(b'old message')
print(old_enc)
new_enc = mulfern.encrypt(b'My Message in Plain Text')
print(new_enc)

try:
    print(old_key.decrypt(new_enc))
except InvalidToken:
    print('old_key failed')
print(mulfern.decrypt(old_enc))
print(mulfern.decrypt(new_enc))
```

Output:

```
b'gAAAAABgo0EvjyAPIc3jHHYBc8iTppwENHPO16S_suoaq3u3UzXUuTcxEmvFr62ZEvw53lPJ9MDYO2A5Ys2dPP77B61jHYbrFQ=='
b'gAAAAABgo0Ev8a4Ixt6HHGVJ8Udkr1gJfjmcfg-Wd96NOR8lrpkhS7USVrZj0WiF74druiZHiDhXxxSt1Wb2CURHYdlZ8-o0SEcEhfOzEl66qgVX2pyNP6Y='
old_key failed
b'old message'
b'My Message in Plain Text'
```

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes it is correct. But one problem with the Fernet is ,it generates the encrypted string more than 120 characters. But need the shorter length like: 32 etc